# How to order_by ini views.py Django by user.first_name

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have the model which has an attribute called **user**.

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

Then, I want to sort my views order_by **user.first_name**. For Example:

```
group = Generus.objects.filter(klp='Marbar').order_by('jenis_kelamin','user.first_name')
```

It is working if just to order_by('jenis_kelamin','user'), but not for order_by('jenis_kelamin','user.first_name').

Is there any solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to access attr in `filter` you need to use `double underscore` but not dot. Like `'user__first_name'`

Try to do:

```
group = Generus.objects.filter(klp='Marbar').order_by('jenis_kelamin','user__first_name')
```